# unbiased estimator for a parameter

Tags: self-study, unbiased-estimator

1000 nodes are randomly sampled from a very large computer network and their “degree” (number of connections to other nodes) is recorded.

> $n= 1000$
> $\bar{x}= 68.266$ 
> $s^2= 8807.2905$ 
> $\operatorname{max}=1294$ 
> $\operatorname{min}= 1$

Let the degrees have a distribution with parameter $β = 3(µ − ½)$ 
An obvious estimator for $β$ is $\hat{β} = 3(\bar{Y}- 1/2)$

> Is this estimator unbiased for $β$? 
> What is its standard error?

When  $β$  and $\hat{β}$  are equal can I assume , 
$$\operatorname{Bias} (\hat{β})= E(\hat{β})-β = 0$$
to conclude this to be unbiased for $β$?

Comment: Please see the [help/on-topic] relating to homework-style questions. You should  clarify your last sentence ($\hat \beta$ is not the same as $\beta$ and that's not the criterion for unbiasedness -- you state it correctly immediately after). Please show some working! What's the value for $E(\bar{Y})$ and hence what's the expectation of the estimator of $\beta$?

Comment: When editing your question, it's best to use MathJax (which implements a subset of LaTeX). There's a tutorial and quick reference [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). You'll need `$\hat{\beta}$` to make $\hat\beta$, `$\bar{Y}$` to make $\bar{Y}$ or  `$\overline{Y}$` for $\overline{Y}$ and so on. Please don't use "o" when you mean $0$. Please use proper capitalization, commas and so on to aid readability (help people to help you; don't make it hard to understand you)

Comment: An estimate $\hat\beta$ of parameter $\beta$ is unbiased if $E(\hat\beta)=\beta.$ In your case it's $E(\hat\beta) =E[3(\bar X - \frac 12)] = 3E(\bar X) - \frac 32 = 3(\mu - \frac 12) = \beta.$ So unbiased/ [Provided that $E(\bar X) = \mu,$ which I assume is true here.)

Comment: @BruceET thank you. for SE $\hat{\beta}$ = \sqrt{(var $\hat{\beta}$)} is used. But here, the sample size is given to be 1000. so, should  I use sqrt (var/n) to calculate SE?

Comment: The SE of $\bar X$ is $\sigma/\sqrt{n}.$ I don't know the context. Do you need to use SE of $\hat\beta?$

Comment: @Bruce given this is clearly a homework style question, it's traditional to leave something for the OP to actually do (per the [help/on-topic] "They get somewhat special treatment, because ultimately you benefit most by finding the solution yourself. The community will try to provide guidance, hints, and useful links"; your comment is pretty much doing the question.)